# How to adjust group generics Ops() in R for a given s3 class?

Tags: r, oop, r-s3

As an exercise to get familiar with OOP in R I want to do the following: There is the `units` package that assigns units (e.g. "gramm" ,"meter" etc.) to numeric data. However the way `Ops.units` is implemented does not allow plus/minus Operations with non-units objects. This leads to compatibility issues with other packages. So my plan is to adjust it. I tried multiple things. First I tried to make a subclass `units2` with its own Ops method that attached units if needed. However other methods of the `units` class return `units` objects instead of `units2` objects. So after such an operation the `units2` Ops method will no longer be used. The second approach is to overwrite `Ops.units`. I tried it as follows:

```
library(units)
old_ops = function(e1,e2,.Generic) {}
body(old_ops) = body(units:::Ops.units)
Ops.units = function(e1,e2){
  

  e = list(e1,e2)
  is_unit = map_lgl(e, ~inherits(.x, "units"))
  if(!all(is_unit) & .Generic %in% c("+","-")){
    #if one of the elements is not a unit, assume the units of the other
    unit_element = e[is_unit][[1]]
    non_unit_element = e[!is_unit][[1]]
    non_unit_element  = set_units(non_unit_element,unit_element, mode = "standard")
    e1 = unit_element
    e2 = non_unit_element
  }
  old_ops(e1,e2,.Generic)
}
```

However `old_ops` needs amongst others the function `.units.simplify` which is not visible and thus returns an error. I could add it to the signature of old_ops and pass it as an argument via `.units.simplify=units:::.units.simplify` but this seems ugly.

Generally I think I may approaching it wrong.
Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you should avoid trying to overwrite methods of an established, well-tested class from an existing package. Write your own class, and include an `as_units` method to convert it if needed for compatibility.